# Könnte mir jemand diesen flachen Witz erklären?

Tags: meaning

In einem Film habe ich Folgendes gehört:

> A: Ich heiße Ronny.
>
> B: Ich kann auch nichts dafür.

Ist das eine Anspielung auf den Namen "Ronny" oder ein allgemeiner Spruch beim Vorstellen?

Comment: Interpretation von Witzen hat nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun.

Comment: &Björn und ich dachte immer, dass man ein gewisses Verständnis für eine Sprache und den kulturellen Kontext braucht, um Witze zu verstehen bzw. zu machen? https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/what-does-guat-mean-in-this-joke,  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/a-joke-from-the-magic-mountain-der-zauberberg-translated-into-english, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29038/what-do-haumich-und-pflaumich-mean, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/kommt-ein-mann-in-eine-kneipe-wieso-haben-witze-diesen-besonderen-satzbau....

Comment: Natürlich sind Witze zum großen Teil sprachspezifisch - versuch' nur mal den mit amerikanischem Bier und Sex im Kanu auf deutsch zu übersetzen.

Comment: Der Witz basiert darauf, dass *Ronny* ein typischer Modename ist. Funktioniert auch mit *Kevin*, *Chantal* und ähnlichen Namen.

Comment: “My name is Ronny. - That's not my fault.“ würde also nicht funktionieren, weil es der deutschen Sprache bedarf?

Comment: I would prefer: "My name is Ronny" - "I am sorry". - By the way, on a funnyness scale from 1 to 10 this is below 1 for me.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: genau. Und das wäre in unterschiedlichen englischsprachigen Ländern dann auch verschieden.  In Neuseeland zum Beispiel würde das mit den Modenamen "Chardonnay" oder "Falcon" funktionieren (Leute aus der Unterschicht haben ihre Tochter da nach Wein und den Sohn nach einem Ford-modell benannt).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das bezieht sich mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit auf den Namen.

Ohne den individuellen Trägern des Namens auf die Füße treten zu wollen, assoziieren viele damit entweder mit jungen Männern der Unterschicht der 80-er Jahre in Westdeutschland (vgl. "Manni" aus den Manta-Witzen), oder mit jemandem jüngeren mit ostdeutschen Wurzeln.

Beide Gruppen werden *pauschal* als weniger privilegiert oder gebildet betrachtet, auch wenn hier natürlich das Klischee regiert.

Comment: Im Prinzip funktioniert der Witz mit jedem Namen ("Mein Name ist [Adolf|Fritz|Hans|Thomas] - Oh. Das tut mir leid"). Mit "Ronnie" funktioniert er nur ein bißchen besser.